# Least significance difference

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I am in a bit of a situation. I used this formula in excel =(STDEV(B2:U2)/SQRT(20))*SQRT(2)*0.5*2.093 long back to calculate LSD. I can think that 20 here means the sample size and 0.5 seems to be the confidence level but I can't remember what is sqrt(2) and 2.093 (is this the t critical value if yes how can I calculate it?).

What I want to do is I have two sets of data, each set has 78 rows that are categories and 20 columns with 20 observations for each category. I am plotting a line graph of these 78 rows on x-axis with the averaged values of 20 columns on y-axis . Now I wan to put LSD as y error bars. I have used the above mentioned formula long back but now can't remember the details.

Comment: Suggest you google 'Fisher LSD' and look at short notes from U Wisconsin and UTD. Both seem clearly and correctly written. That would save me some typing. // If you are making more than a couple of comparisons, I'd recommend 'Tukey HSD' instead, but not sure that's available in Excel.

Comment: Hi @BruceET thanks for comments. I only have  vague idea of what I am trying to achieve without knowing much statistics but its urgent. So I have around 78 data points that I want to plot in a line graph. Each data point is an average over 20 values. If I am plotting two of such lines next to each other I want to show some kind of error bars that would show the significance of mean/average values. To be exact I want to show that if error bars overlap between the two lines then there is no significant difference and if they do not overlap then those points are significantly different.

Comment: I am not a big fan of 'error bars' because they are easily misinterpreted. If you suspect a difference as some particular point, then do the test. The issue is that if you do _many_ comparisons each with 95% confidence, then what is the overall confidence for the 'family' of all the comparisons?